# Draw a thick line between dots in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I want to connect two dots with a line in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqrpg2ky/). When I click the blue circle, it automatically generates a line following mouse move. And I clicks the red circle to draw the line.

The problem is: When I set the line width bigger than 1.

```
node.attr("stroke-width", "5");
```

The click function of the red circle is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the thicker line is getting in the way of the mouse coords, try something like this:

```
$("#raphaelContainer").bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    x = e.offsetX + 5;
    y = e.offsetY + 5;
    line.updateEnd(x, y);
});
```

Comment: Did this help you? If so please mark as correct by selecting the tick next to the answer